# adding extra data to ajax response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this piece of code:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url:      "/customers/shipments/get_carrier_products_and_prices_for_shipment.json",
    type:     "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data:     data
})
```

and the last lines of controller:

```
if @carrier_products_and_prices.length > 0
    @digest = params[:digest]
    @html     = render_to_string(partial: "components/customers/shipments/carrier_products_and_prices_for_shipment_table.html.haml", locals: {carrier_products_and_prices: @carrier_products_and_prices})
else
    @html = render_to_string(partial: "components/customers/shipments/no_carrier_products_available.html.haml", locals: {carrier_products_and_prices: @carrier_products_and_prices})
end
```

Which hits a rails controller. My question is, how can I control/append extra data to the response object that rails returns? Right now, it only returns a html string, and I would like to also be able to send a response ID with it

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your client is expecting a JSON body. Just create a hash of the values you want returned to the client and call `render json: hash` where `hash` contains the values you want to return to the client as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using the JSON `dataType`, there's nothing stopping you from packing up your stuff in an object:

```
{
  "html": "<div>...</div>",
  "responseID": 69
}
```

Comment: I am already sending a request ID to the controller, but I want the controller to return that same ID, but as a response ID

Comment: You're not showing the part of your controller that returns the response; I showed you what response can look like. You can get it by something as simple as `render json: { html: @html, responseID: responseID }` (adjust to your code as necessary).